# extract in postgresql date

Tags: postgresql, date

I have a question about `extract` function in PostgreSQL.

I am generating reports about last month's data.

So far no problem:

```
where extract (month from date) = extract(month from current_date- '1 month'::interval)
```

But the problem with this setup is that when the data spans more than 1 year than more months will be included.

To handle this I can add another condition for year:

```
and extract (year from date) = extract (year from current_date)
```

But this will cause a problem when generating report about December in January.

How can I generate my report about December in January without the fear that I include more months.

Comment: harmic is correct. In case you have some kind of data warehouse, you can add new column to time dimension. For example we do have column `is_previous_month boolean` in our time dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
WHERE date_trunc('month',date)=date_trunc('month',current_date) - interval '1 month'
```

Comment: Ah Thank you very much.  I see what you are getting at. I'm using jaspersoft report and in a report i can add the columns and create variables corresponding to the columns.  Thanks a lot!  (I don't have 15 rep so I can't vote your answer up. .)

Comment: @Sjoerdjump if this answer works for you, you should be able to accept it even without any rep

Comment: tested it and it worked like a charm :) Thanks again!